# XAMPP: Connecting to localhost fix? [Persistent]

Tags: apache

I just installed XAMPP Windows 1.8.2 in my computer. Port 80 is secured and in use by Apache there are no problems nor any port conflicts. I always open Xampp and start both Apache and MySQL Modules in the control panel. Both modules are running, Whenever I click on the Apache admin button it redirects me to the localhost page, It takes a while to load and then this error shows up.

[image: Network Error (tcp_error)]

If it's too small for you guys the error says: Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Another error shows up if i try with `127.0.0.1`: [image: Access forbidden!]

The localhost changes to `130.147.134.66` NOTE: I use a proxy network and the IP address is `130.147.134.251`.

I have tried changing and updating the hosts file in the `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts.` but the problem still persists.

Keep that in mind I am new to using Xampp, and its been only a week since I started using phpMyAdmin and MySQL

My httpd-xampp.conf file:

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /security "C:/xampp/security/htdocs/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/security/htdocs">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
   </Directory>

    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I've almost the same problem, I'm receiving "Connection refused: localhost:8012" error.

Comment: Edit: this was happening because of the Opera Turbo.

Answer (score 3):

It's already giving you the answer.
Look at your second picture.

```
This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf"
```

How to "fix" this:

either:
 disable your proxy for local addresses
or:

```
   1) open the file "\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf" in a texteditor
   2) replace "Allow from localhost" with "Allow from YOURLOCALIP" (2 times)
   3) save the file
   4) restart Apache
```

See http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=32503#p131519 too

**Edit:**

It's in line 120-128:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16 \
        YOURLOCALIP <--------------------------------------------------------------

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Can you tell me in line 2) replace "Allow from localhost" with "Allow from YOURLOCALIP" (2 times) what do you mean by "(2 times)" ?

Comment: In the old versions of xampp / wampp there were two entries to change. If you're using the latest version (what you should do of course) it's only the part mentioned in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your security configuration for XAMPP is specified in the LocationMatch as chill0r mentioned, on lines 120-128.

Your configuration is allowing from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \, fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16, and fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16 which will never be matched since you're using a proxy AND it's denying everything. This is where the Order statement comes in. It tells your configuration to match against deny first then allow, so it will always deny since you have Deny all.

You need to change your configuration so that it doesn't deny everything and allows at least your own IP. Since it sounds like your running a local dev environment and not exposing it, you can consider removing all restrictions:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Allow from all

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

If you do this, configure your firewall prevent port 80 access from outside your network (this can be done on your machine or router). Alternatively, you can configure it to work for an IP range using a partial IP that includes your proxy:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 130.147.134

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Notice that the Order changed from deny,allow to allow,deny so it will check against the allow statement first.

---

I also noticed that the two requests were for different paths, the first one is "/" and the second is "/xampp/" and the latter is the one that wasn't refused.

In your IfModule alias_module you should add an alias:

```
Alias "/" "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp"
```

This will help you get off the ground, but you'll need to make sure to learn about the directives, specifically Alias and AliasMatch as your routing gets more complicated. Alternatively, you could just develop in the C:/xampp/htdocs/ directory instead of C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the XAMPP server make sure that other running services are closed like Skype and other servers which is using the same port number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is easier than other answers.

1) Install XAMPP in your pc, in this case, Windows 8.
2) Start > Administrative Tools > Services > Web Deployment Agent service and press STOP.

Usually Web Deployment uses port 80 which is the port used by XAMPP by default. If you stop that process and write localhost in your web browser you should be able to access phpmyadmin.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: need to more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below Steps

1. In XAMPP on the Apache Module ,Select Config button **httpd.conf**
2. Comment "**Deny from all**" in the following section,

   ```
   <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
           Order deny,allow
          #Deny from all
           Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
                   fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
                   fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

           ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </LocationMatch>
   ```
3. **Restart** the XAMPP (Important Step)