# Xampp works but i can't connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I can't access localhost.
I'm using Xampp and it works, mysql and apache works too.

I googled it but nothing helped, can you suggest something?

> Error is:This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost intro
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 1):

This could occur due to number of reasons since application such as Skype do use the same port as `Apache`, which could prevent the service from running. So what if you close your `Skype` instance and start trying it again or maybe you could change the default port without pointing it to 80. There's a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508774/xampp-this-webpage-is-not-available).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have closed skype but it doesn't helped me.

Comment: @I.loe what if you change your port from `httpd-xampp.conf`? [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971263/xampp-connecting-to-localhost-fix-persistent)

Comment: i can't find any port there